# Use WhatsApp desktop or web without a connection on my phone

Tags: whatsapp

I work offshore so have no connection to my phone whatsoever but want to use desktop WhatsApp.

I have no way to verify the IR code.

Is there a way I can use WhatsApp desktop or web?

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't, as it's required to scan the QR code to be able to use WebApps on a web browser and it's required that the phone be connected  (reference https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/web/28080003 )

Also see [Whatsapp Web: "Phone Not Connected"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87858/whatsapp-web-phone-not-connected).